# ASP.net MVC 4 database error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small problem with mvc 4  , unfortunately it is sunday so I cannot ask my teacher.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxRGP.png

What is the mistake I make in MVC 4? I'm used to MVC 3.

Exactly this code works in visual studio 2010 and not in visual studio 2012.

[image]

Comment: What is a `JabContainer`?  Should it have a property called `Jab`?  I see a `Jab` edmx file there, what is its type?

Comment: JabContainer is the database ( right under in the server explorer)

Comment: I am not sure what the type is of the jab edmx file. We just started at school and I upgraded to visual studio 2012.

Comment: Anyone else with an genius idea?

Comment: Your project may be using templates to generate models from the edmx file. And model "Jab" might not be generated. Try this: right click on the edmx file or Jab.Context.tt file and you will find some options to run some custom tool. Once that tool is run you will get the class "Jab" created. If the project is using some custom template this should work.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam I'm trying now! Didn't worked. The class Jab.cs were indeed created by the custom tool. But It still doesn't give me an option to use the database.